# IIS does not expose correct Let's Encrypt certificate?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a couple of website hosted on an IIS 8.5 instance. I have used [letsencrypt-win-simple](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple) to generate certificates. This tool also install the certificates into IIS. I had reports that some browsers, mainly Android phones, are not able to use website, because of SSL errors.

This is a sample output from `openssl`:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ad.adtube.ir:443 -servername ad.adtube.ir
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = ad.adtube.ir
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = ad.adtube.ir
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

I had this error before, but I did solve it in Apache. It was a misconfiguration. I can not find anything related to IIS. This is the first time I have to operate an IIS instance, pitty :)

Anyway, what can I do? I have also checked SSL Labs, and the symptoms of the problem are the same as [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/android-doesnt-trust-the-certificate/16498), for example. Everyone mentions Apache, as if it should not happen in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was the old X1 certificate lingering around. The solution posted [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/iis-8-5-building-incorrect-chain-with-lets-encrypt-authority-x3/13320/84) worked for me.

Here is the instructions:

> To get to it, you need to download PsTools from SysInternals212 and
>   run psexec -i -s mmc.exe, go to File -> Add-Remove Snap-in, choose
>   Certificates and My user account. Now go into Intermediate Certificate
>   Authorities and you should find that elusive X1 certificate hiding
>   there.
>
> It might be enough to remove the X1 and then restart IIS, but I ended
>   up adding X3 certificate here just to be sure (right click on the
>   certificate list - click All Tasks -> Import and choose the X3 file).
>
> After this you need to "touch" the bindings in IIS (for example,
>   change the certificate and then back again or delete/add the binding)
>   and after IIS is then restarted it will finally start to serve the
>   correct chain.